# R function pretty() not showing expected result

Tags: r

I'm not that good in programming R, maybe somebody can help me.
I used pretty() function on some histograms (for breaks=) but sometimes got an error. Further testing brought me to following results:

```
pretty(-1:1,n=20)
```

[1] -1.0 -0.9 -0.8 -0.7 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9  1.0

That's what I expected, also with the following line of code

```
pretty(-26:71,n=18)
```

[1] -30 -25 -20 -15 -10  -5   0   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75

**BUT** - here comes the problem, following pretty() usage brought a complete wrong result (not even getting above zero)

```
pretty(-0.26:0.71,n=10)
```

[1] -0.35 -0.30 -0.25 -0.20

Can anybody explain to me what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Maybe you meant `pretty(seq(-0.26, 0.71, .01), n=10)`. `-0.26:0.71` is.equal to `-.26` as `:` makes a sequence with a step size of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description of `pretty` from `help(pretty)` does a good job explaining the purpose:

> Compute a sequence of about n+1 equally spaced ‘round’ values which cover the range of the values in x. The values are chosen so that they are 1, 2 or 5 times a power of 10.

Your first call included the sequence `-1:1`:

```
-1:1
[1] -1  0  1

pretty(-1:1,n=20)
 [1] -1.0 -0.9 -0.8 -0.7 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2
[14]  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9  1.0
```

You got some nice values that cover `-1` to `1`. The same is true for your second call.

However, your third call included the sequence `-0.26:0.71`. The following are equivallent:

```
-0.26:0.71
[1] -0.26
seq(-0.26,0.71,by = 1)
[1] -0.26
```

Since `-0.26` and `0.71` are closer together than `1`, you only get a single value returned.

Therefore, `pretty(-0.26,n=10)` makes a nice sequence around `-0.26`:

```
pretty(-0.26,n=10)
[1] -0.35 -0.30 -0.25 -0.20
```

Perhaps instead you'd prefer this:

```
pretty(c(-0.26,0.71),n=10)
 [1] -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8
```

The code underlying `pretty` is somewhat complicated. But you can see the function by typing `pretty.default` at the console and reviewing the C source [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/17a72a9634734e009094fd8b48e985b8597ced6a/src/main/util.c#L2690-L2728).

Answer (score 1):

Another way of dealing with it is to multiply by 10 and then divide by 10 again.

```
 pretty((10*-0.26):(10*0.71), n=10)/10
 [1] -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7
```